# Se puede enviar datos desde un component.ts a un servicio en angular 6,7,8

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy tratando de obtener datos desde un servicio, los datos se originan en el `component`.

Quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de que llegen los datos o tendré que mover mi método.

Esta es la forma en la que emito mis datos desde el componente:

```
 @Output() permisosEmit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

Asi emito

```
 this.Service.metodo(variable).subscribe(
   result => {
       this.permisosEmit.emit(result);
   }
);
```

Pero como el servicio no tiene `html` donde insertar el `selector` no se como recibirlo.

Codigo de mi servicio

```
@Injectable()
export class ModuleValidationService {
    private resulStore: any;
    private moduleValid = false;
    constructor(private router: Router) {
    }

public Metodo(modulo) {
    this.resulStore = resulato;
    if (this.resulStore !== null && this.resulStore !== undefined) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('Permisos') !== null && localStorage.getItem('Permisos') !== undefined) {

             const permisosUsuario = // aqui deberia de obtener los datos que emito desde el component;
             permisosUsuario.forEach(element => {

                if (modulo === element.IdModulo) {
                    this.moduleValid = true;
                }
            });
            if (!this.moduleValid) {
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
            }

        }
    } else {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/Login');
        localStorage.clear();
    }}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es pasar datos del componente al servicio no uses el Emitter, solo agrega un método al servicio y le pasas ahí los datos para que el servicio los use:

```
@Injectable()
export class ModuleValidationService {
    private resulStore: any;
    private moduleValid = false;
    constructor(private router: Router) {
    }
recibirDatos(datos){
    //hacer lo que sea con los datos recibidos del componente
}
//resto del codigo del servicio

}
```

Luego en el componente haces esto:

```
this.Service.recibirDatos(datos);
```

De esa forma puedes enviar datos del componente al servicio.