# Pasar valor desde servicio a componente

Tags: angular, servicio

estoy trabajando en un proyecto en Angular y necesito pasar un valor desde un componente a un servicio. Se como hacerlo a la inversa, es decir, desde un servicio a un componente "inyectando" el servicio en el componente (en el constructor).

¿Alguna solucion?

Gracias, Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Hace unos días respondí un problema similar, te dejo el enlace:

[Pasar datos de componente a Servicio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/274944/se-puede-enviar-datos-desde-un-component-ts-a-un-servicio-en-angular-6-7-8/275127#275127)

Si eso no resuelve tu problema con gusto te ayudo a encontrar otra solución.